# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 error message

Tags: java

I am writing some code trying to split a string (01/04/2010) into 3 different integers. When I try to run it, I get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error.

Here is the code:

```
public Date(String date) {

    String dayz[];
    dayz = date.split("/");

    int m=Integer.parseInt(dayz[0]);
    int d=Integer.parseInt(dayz[1]);
    int y=Integer.parseInt(dayz[2]);
    if(y<100) { 
        y=Integer.parseInt(dayz[2])+2000;
    }

    setComponents(m,d,y);


}
```

Here is the setComponents method:

```
 public void setComponents(int month, int day, int year) {

    if (month < 1 || month > 12 || year < MIN_YEAR || day < 1 || day >     numDaysInMonth(month, year)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    this.month = month;
    this.day = day;
    this.year = year;

}
```

Any help?

Comment: What are the stack traces of the errors you're getting?

Comment: And where does the date String come from? You are sure it is exactly of the form '01/04/2010' ?

Comment: note: I suggest you use `y += 2000` instead of `y=Integer.parseInt(dayz[2])+2000;`

Comment: in what line you get the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` ?... You sure you are getting a date like you expect?

Comment: Works fine for me with `String date = "01/04/2010";`

Comment: Please edit your post and provide us with the stack trace from your exception.

Comment: Do you know [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)?

Comment: Harry is right.  The only way I can see this messing up is if you're string isn't date format.

Comment: yes, it is in the form of 01/04/2010 or any other date with the same format

Comment: I agree with Harry as well. Check the inputs as there is probably something off there. This method of parsing it, while a bit rough around the edges, should work.

Comment: oh I just realized that I am supposed to check for 04/10, which should not work and it supposed to print out a message. Maybe that's what is wrong. Any idea for how to improve the code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use StringTokenizer. Its much cleaner and simple to use.

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String []args){
        String a="01/04/2010";
        StringTokenizer st= new StringTokenizer(a,"/");
        int data[] = new int[3];
        int count =0;
        while(st.hasMoreElements())
        {
            data[count++]=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        }

        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
            System.out.println(data[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment: **oh I just realized that I am supposed to check for 04/10, which should not work and it supposed to print out a message. Maybe that's what is wrong. Any idea for how to improve the code?**

```
public Date(String date) {

  String dayz[];
  dayz = date.split("/");

  if(days.length < 3)
  {
    System.err.println("Invalid date: " + date + ". It should be in the format 'DD/MM/YYYY.");
  }
  else
  {
    int m=Integer.parseInt(dayz[0]);
    int d=Integer.parseInt(dayz[1]);
    int y=Integer.parseInt(dayz[2]);
    if(y<100) { 
      y=Integer.parseInt(dayz[2])+2000;
    }
    setComponents(m,d,y);
  }
}
```